# 302 Redirect Loop on /wp-admin/

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

When going to https://www.example.com/wp-admin , an endless loop of 302 redirects occur. A few things about the error:

This only happens on wp-admin and every redirect is to https://www.example.com/wp-admin/ (it is not looping back to http or anything like that)

I can login at wp-login, it redirects to wp-admin/ and I get the loop error. However, I do get the admin toolbar when I go back to the site. Anytime I try to access the dashboard, loop error.

If I access the customizer on the toolbar, I get a 404 error at https://www.example.com/wp-admin/customize.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F.

Prior to yesterday, I was able to access wp-admin without trouble

A week or so ago, I was getting 404 error on all the custom pages other than the home page. I am still unsure what caused that. I reset the permalinks to solve that issue.

Some of the debugging I've tried:

Cleared Cookies, different browser, incognito mode

Revert to default wordpress .htaccess folder, disabled w3 total cache in config

Disabled plugins by changing plugin folder name

Disabled themes by changing plugin folder name

https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/

Change wp-admin folder name - this gives me a 500 error instead of the redirect

A few other notes:

I noticed in the wp-content folder there are a few files titled deleteme.817d2586a14e49e6b41133b495df2c1b.php. Which google says is from installatron. I tried commenting out the contents, but still get the wp-admin loop error.

In cpanel, on the installatron application page, there is a link for example.com/wp-admin/**. When I click it, it redirects to https://www.example.com/wp-content/deleteme.217cc51e4488487cb5b2e4cf6e1b066e.php?bb3553b474819b5425c368200327d3131 which returns a 404 error

For migration, the client installed wordpress using installatron on their server. I gave him a db using wp-migrate, and the appropriate wp-content folders. I am not familiar with installatron.

It feels like installatron is running some job that is clashing with my wp. That would also help explain the permalinks issue from a week ago.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Is there anything else I can do to debug?

edit: Nothing in error_log on the root, error_log in wp-admin, or debug.log

Comment: check your error.log file in your cpanel file manager.

Comment: @psychodeveloper
Nothing in error_log on the root, error_log in wp-admin, or debug.log